# Retrofit 2 how to get the response from nested json objects (android)

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

this is my first json response and i got the token

```
{
"token": "I0ZmEifQ.CdbGWjkIYnuO29uJokCIGn8kXFbLbVp3gnlsEszagno"
}
```

pojo class

```
public class TokenReceiver {
    private String token; 

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

the above worked fine but how to get the response for below

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Super",
    "last_name": "Admin",
    "email": "abc@sad.sdf",
    "mobile_no": 2147483647,
    "created_at": "2016-01-21 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-21 00:00:00",
    "user_role_id": 1
  }
}
```

the status code is 200 (OK)
but the data is not getting attached to the pojo

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String first_name;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String last_name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("mobile_no")
    @Expose
    private String mobile_no;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String created_at;

    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updated_at;

    @SerializedName("user_role_id")
    @Expose
    private int user_role_id;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hope it will help you ! just open this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and select Source type: JSON and Annotation style: GSON and dump you full JSON there, you'll get full pojo ready, that you can paste it to your Project Code. and that POJO class you can set as a CallBack in Retrofit !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class Response{
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private User user;
  }
```

---

```
public class User{

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;

@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String first_name;

@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String last_name;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("mobile_no")
@Expose
private String mobile_no;

@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String created_at;

@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updated_at;

@SerializedName("user_role_id")
@Expose
private int user_role_id;
}
```

---

Inner Response can be accessed by below mentioned.

```
response.getUser().getId();
```

Comment: thanks a lot :)             Response obj =response.body()         can i use this  object(obj ) only inside retrofit's onResponse method?

Comment: yes your are correct..you should send root object of Response-- new Callback<Response>()

Comment: how can i use that object outside the onResponse method?

Comment: create Response variable as Global.Response response;then assign onResponse value to that.

Comment: What's '@Expose`?  Never heard of it.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky  refer this  com.google.gson.annotations package in GSON for '@Expose'

Answer (score 1):

```
Public class classname{

public User user;
 class User{

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;

@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String first_name;

@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String last_name;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("mobile_no")
@Expose
private String mobile_no;

@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String created_at;

@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updated_at;

@SerializedName("user_role_id")
@Expose
private int user_role_id;
}
}
```

Above code will work for you

Comment: Thankyou  dude                                                                         Classname obj =response1.body();       //assign                        Log.d("MainActivity2", "email = " + response1.body().user.getEmail()); 
Log.d("MainActivity2", "email = " + obj.user.getEmail());                        after assigning which is the correct method to call ...both prints the email:)

Comment: Ok. If it works means accept the answer may be it will helpful for someone